# Is it possible to make gnome's "run command" show real time suggestion?

Tags: gnome

Basically if I would type f it would show all apps starting with f like firefox etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use <kbd>Super</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> instead of <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd>it shows the list of all applications and then in the `Type to Search` dialogue, it will present all application beginning with what you have typed (such as Firefox, Files etc).

[Here](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/shell-keyboard-shortcuts.html.en) is a link to other useful Gnome keyboard shortcuts.